# Async/Await on Callback not waiting

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am querying AMPS SOW using javascript API. My functions look like this:

```
sow_query = async(topic, filter, options) => {
await this.connection
await this.client.sow(this.onMessage, topic, filter, options)
return this.message
}

onMessage = (message)=>{
this.message.push(message.data)
}

//Calling functions
const getData = async(date) =>{
let data = await getAmpsData(date)
}

async getAmpsData(date){
const filter = "some filter"
const data = await ampsClient.sow_query(topic, filter)
data.forEach((element) => console.log(element))
}
```

It looks like my call to ampsClient.sow_query doesnt wait for the callback to finish so returns an empty list. Therefore, I cannot loop through the data in my calling function getAmpsData.
I know it has to do with async/await because if I simply do console.log(data) in getAmpsData i can see the data (perhaps after 2 seconds) when the promise is resolved. Is there anyway i can get this working?

Comment: What is `ampsClient` anyway? Is there documentation for it?

Comment: `await this.connection` looks weird, and so does the `await this.client.sow` call that passes an `onMessage` callback. Can you please post the full class and documentation on the `connection` and `client` objects?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, `data` in `getAmpsData` is an array as expected, but `data` in `getData` is undefined. It's not an async/await problem, you just forgot to add `return data;` to `getAmpsData`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Dont think it has to do with return. The issue is i cant even access the data in getAmpsData function. When I try to loop through, it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure about what package you are using. But, maybe, it using a callback function to get the result of `.sow` function - `message.data`.

With your logic, `onMessage` function will be called after `data.forEach` done, you can try adding a `console.log` line to `onMessage` function.

Maybe, the package has an important reason to do that. But, to fix this issue, you can wrap `.sow` function into a promise.

```js
sow_query = async (topic, filter, options) => {
  await this.connection // ???
  return new Promise((resolve) => { // wrap in a promise
    this.client.sow( // no need to wait .sow
      (message) => {
        resolve(message.data); // just resolve when we get the message's data
      },
      topic, filter, options)
  });
}

//Calling functions
const getData = async (date) => {
  let data = await getAmpsData(date)
}

async getAmpsData(date) {
  const filter = "some filter"
  const data = await ampsClient.sow_query(topic, filter)
  data.forEach((element) => console.log(element))
}
```

Comment: I think your hunch is correct, but [never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Comment: @Bergi Ahh, thanks for reminding me! Maybe I need to wrap all logic inside Promise constructor to a `try/catch` block, and throw an error via `reject` param.